# How can I create a basic Soap server with spyne in django

Tags: django, soap, spyne

I want to create a server which uses Django and make and take response as SOAP, so I try to use spyne for this reason but I can't run the given code

```
class HelloWorldService(ServiceBase):
    @rpc(Unicode, Integer, _returns=Iterable(Unicode))
    def say_hello(ctx, name, times):
        """Docstrings for service methods appear as documentation in the wsdl.
        <b>What fun!</b>
        @param name the name to say hello to
        @param times the number of times to say hello
        @return the completed array
        """

        for i in range(times):
            yield u'Hello, %s' % name


application = Application([HelloWorldService], 'spyne.examples.hello.soap',
                          in_protocol=Soap11(validator='lxml'),
                          out_protocol=Soap11())

wsgi_application = WsgiApplication(application)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import logging

    from wsgiref.simple_server import make_server

    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
    logging.getLogger('spyne.protocol.xml').setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

    logging.info("listening to http://127.0.0.1:8000")
    logging.info("wsdl is at: http://localhost:8000/?wsdl")

    server = make_server('127.0.0.1', 8000, wsgi_application)
    server.serve_forever()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove validator='lxml' option in in_protocol

I don't know the reason, the validator took a long time response or did not work.

And add import statements

```
from spyne import Application, rpc, ServiceBase, Iterable, Integer, Unicode

from spyne.protocol.soap import Soap11
from spyne.server.wsgi import WsgiApplication

class HelloWorldService(ServiceBase):
    @rpc(Unicode, Integer, _returns=Iterable(Unicode))
    def say_hello(ctx, name, times):
        """Docstrings for service methods appear as documentation in the wsdl.
        <b>What fun!</b>
        @param name the name to say hello to
        @param times the number of times to say hello
        @return the completed array
        """

        for i in range(times):
            yield u'Hello, %s' % name


application = Application([HelloWorldService], 'spyne.examples.hello.soap',
                in_protocol=Soap11(),
                out_protocol=Soap11())

wsgi_application = WsgiApplication(application)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import logging

    from wsgiref.simple_server import make_server

    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
    logging.getLogger('spyne.protocol.xml').setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

    logging.info("listening to http://127.0.0.1:8000")
    logging.info("wsdl is at: http://localhost:8000/?wsdl")

    server = make_server('127.0.0.1', 8000, wsgi_application)
    server.serve_forever()
```

#### This is my test result by Postman and curl

Body of POST commend

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <say_hello xmlns="spyne.examples.hello.soap">
        <name>Tom Cruise</name>
        <times>3</times>
    </say_hello>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

[image]

#### curl POST commend with XML lint for terminal pipeline

```
$ curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost:8000' --header 'Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8' --header 'SOAPAction: say_hello' --data-raw '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <say_hello xmlns="spyne.examples.hello.soap">
        <name>Tom Cruise</name>
        <times>3</times>
    </say_hello>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
' | xmllint --format -
```

```
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   707  100   427  100   280   9319   6111 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 15711
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap11env:Envelope xmlns:soap11env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tns="spyne.examples.hello.soap">
  <soap11env:Body>
    <tns:say_helloResponse>
      <tns:say_helloResult>
        <tns:string>Hello, Tom Cruise</tns:string>
        <tns:string>Hello, Tom Cruise</tns:string>
        <tns:string>Hello, Tom Cruise</tns:string>
      </tns:say_helloResult>
    </tns:say_helloResponse>
  </soap11env:Body>
</soap11env:Envelope>
```

And my python version and spyne version

```
$ python --version
Python 3.10.4

$ pip show spyne
Name: spyne
Version: 2.14.0
```